# When does GHC internally mutate immutable values?

Tags: haskell, optimization, real-time, immutability, ghc

I wish to use Haskell for a realtime application that consists of a ever-changing heavy state.

The state is immutable, of course, so at every state-step I will re-create a new slightly-changed state and discard the old one. It would turn out painfully inefficient in this instance, because I have no need for the previous states.

I often encountered people saying that GHC can optimize those kind of stuff and internally mutate immutable values, and I want to make sure that it will.

Is it possible? is there a way to determine if GHC will optimize it by internally mutating the value? is there a way to enforce it / make sure it will?

P.S. Is there a formal name for this optimization?

Comment: You might want to be a little more concrete by "recreate a new slightly-changed state". I think you might be asking about sharing, or about how GHC represents data on the heap.

Answer (score 9):

GHC itself doesn't do this. Various container libraries use a trick called *stream fusion*, which means some copies that the pure-functional code suggests aren't actually ever made – but this is still not true "internal mutation", rather it groups together multiple operations that would each involve a copy to one single big operation with still only one copy.

I don't think it's really feasible to get true "mutation-optimisation" in a fully automatic way; some languages like [Mercury](http://mercurylang.org/) kind of claim they do it, but I don't really know how well it works.

However, a good pure functional language like Haskell is quite capable of *explicitly* dealing with mutable state: through monads. This can either be the "omnipotent" `IO` monad (somewhat frowned upon because you lose all ref-transp. guarantees, but for a realtime application this is probably the right thing), or the specialised [`ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html), whose purpose is specifically to allow you using true mutable state while keeping the outside behaviour of the program purely-functional.
If you take such an approach, you not only make *sure* there won't be costly copies made, you also probably end up with nicer code. Because sometimes mutation is just the right way to think about some problem; even code that's really pure-functional sometimes gets nicer if you "pretend" to use mutable state, in the [`State` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State.html).

Comment: You mentioned just for the `IO` monad that it's probably the right thing for real-time. Are you excluding `ST` or would it probably serve me just as well?

Comment: @MasterMastic: `ST` should be fine.

Comment: @MasterMastic: `IO` and `ST` are in fact the same as far as mutable state is concerned; the difference is simply that `ST` doesn't allow you to perform file reads, random number access etc.. Hence its end-to-end performance is referentially transparent; you can therefore embed a mutable `ST` algorithm safely into a purely-functional program (with `runST`; when using `IO`, this would require `unsafePerformIO`, we don't want that). But if you're in the `IO` monad anyway, you might as well use it for the mutable state, too.

Comment: GHC actually does perform this optimization very occasionally (it has a name which I'm trying to remember), but it's not at all thorough about detecting when it's applicable.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK `ghc` doesn't perform such the optimization in general case. It probably requires [unique types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type).

But it's runtime is optimized for such "slightly-changed state" case. Usually your state is (or can be represented as) something like a tree, and most of manges actually reuse most of existing tree. So modification operated only few pointers, and is very efficient. Consider the example:

```
data State = State
  { theA :: A
  , theB :: B
  }

data A = A Int
data B = B String

modifyTheA :: (A -> A) -> State -> State
modifyTheA f s = s {theA = f (theA s)}
```

Here `modifyTheA` function creates new `State`, but it is just two pointers. The whole `theB` string is reused.

Comment: Manually notifying the compiler that such an optimization is possible would require unique types, but there are a couple of cases where GHC does this on its own (such as when an object's declaration and last use are in the same function)

Answer (score 2):

GHC does this optimization on one condition: if an object is used once in the function where it's declared and no additional references to it are created. It isn't applied if the object is created and used in separate functions unless the source function is inlined.

There is another related optimization that GHC does more reliably. If a function's last action is to call itself with mostly the same arguments then it won't even touch the arguments that are unchanged.